Data Preparation: 2d Skeleton Data for MMAction2 Skeleton based action recognition
I am building a pipeline for action recognition. I am basically generating 2D skeleton data with YOLO pose and then I want to use the 2D skeleton data for action recognition.
For action recognition, I am using the first in this list (bone):
https://mmaction2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_zoo/skeleton.html#ntu120-xsub-2d
My problem lies in preparation of the 2D skeleton data:
YOLO-Pose has this structure:
"YOLO-Pose-Structure that I captured"
However MMAction ST-GCN-Skeleton-based-recognition needs a different structure as input.
If I'm not mistaken the input file to the action recognition has to be JSON format. Also it needs to have a specific format of how the 2D skeleton data is prepared. I tried going through mmaction2-documentation but could not find anything. I tried googling but am lacking the right words to find the right documentation. Last resort ChatGPT just gave me a headache.
